# Check if SIM card exists

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application and I need a functionality for a user to send an SMS (sms compose task, easy), but before that I'd like to check if sending SMS is possible somehow.

So my question is **How to check if phone has SIM installed (or calling/sending SMS is possible)?**

I've been trying to google it for some time but didn't get anywhere close to any usable or informative search result.

P.S.: My app also uses webservices so there is another question related to it: **Is there a way to check if any internet connection is available?**

*(The second question is not that important, the first one is bothering me)*

Comment: Is there no way to simply ping a site to check if there is a connection to the net? I'd say do the same thing to check if there is a SIM (Mobile data), but this may not be effective due to the high availability of WiFi. Another question is, how many phones actually work without a SIM? I know emulators do (Which is maybe why you want to check)..

Comment: @NewAmbition ALL phones have by law to work without SIMS, though only for emergency calls. 911 has to be processed without contract.

Comment: @TomTom I understand that, but excuse my naivety, would an SMS work (Which was my point)?

Comment: @NewAmbition Not sure. Seriously. If yes then only to 911 ;) It may well be (to allow emergency calls from people that can not speak for whatever reason).

Comment: @TomTom I'd assume the same (IF one could actually send an SMS - would would depend on the phone or if the 911 service actually caters for it). Some testing from the OP should be done in this regard :)

Comment: @NewAmbition Why the heck should he? As in: unless his case is "send sms to 911" this is irrelevant. All what was wrong was your question whether phones work without SIM card.

Comment: @TomTom what do you mean? IF one could send an SMS to 911 (Without a SIM), then if he checked, his return would always be `true`, even though he wouldn't be able to send an SMS to any other number?

Comment: @NewAmbition Yes, exactly. Man, you seriously need to get some reading about how mobile phones work.

Comment: @TomTom you just went in a full loop questioning what I said to eventually agreeing with it? So much for a useful Q&A site.

Comment: You guys, are adorable :) I'd send you both a cookie, but I don't think you would be satisfied with it. Well, I got my answer in the whirlwind of your comments, so thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if any internet connection is available?

Sure. Connect to your service, run a ping to a known location. Make sure not to do it too often due to costs for the user.

> How to check if phone has SIM installed (or calling/sending SMS is possible)?

Not possible. Not too sensible - IIRC SMS is available if the phone is logged into a SIM and that is a 99.9999% chance. People do not run apps on phones without sim cards ;) (though technically the one reason is to have a phone in your car for emergencies - networks HAVE to process 911 without a valid, with no or with a blocked SIM card, which is why the phone says "emergency calls only" when you start it without SIM.

But normally I would assume SMS are available.

Thee is an API to check the operator, but that does not mean that the operator will process SMS.... the card may well be temporarily blocked (imagine: out of money prepaid card - can log in, can receive calls, can not send).

Comment: Valid point of view. Thanks, as you presented it I realized I do not exactly need to check it, just got too deep into my ways of thinking I thought I needed it.BTW: For example me, as a "developer" (still not sure I have the right to use the title), I have 4 or 5 phones on my table (depending on the day of week, testers, bosses mood and position of constelations) and only two of them have SIM cards, although all of them have applications installed, contacts loaded, are connected to Wi-Fi etc.

Comment: @mishan Yeah, but you may realize that most people actually USE Phones, and do not just develop on them. The use case of a developer is EXTREMELY rare, in terms of percentages ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
//To check internet connection 
if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
{
MessageBox.Show("Network available");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("No Network");
}

//To check mobile operator
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator))
{
MessageBox.Show(DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Sadly that does not work - logged in does not mean getting service as the card may be blocked. THe question asks for ability to send sms, not availability of operator. Not being able to send sms may be for example a prepaid card without credits left.

Comment: @TomTom: Well, this method, even though it's not ideal, is enough workaround for me to work with. :) I'd be happy if there was better way, but as a basic check this  is enough.